# How to use hl-line-mode to highlight just one (1) line when visual-line-mode is enabled

Tags: emacs, elisp

Does anyone have an alternative to, or a modification of, `hl-line-mode` so that just one (1) horizontal line will be highlighted when `visual-line-mode` is enabled?

Presently, the entire word-wrapped line gets highlighted, even though it may span several horizontal lines.  I'm using a fairly recent version of Emacs Trunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to control this using `hl-line-range-function`, giving it code that stops at the position used by `end-of-visual-line`.

(100% untested -- just checked the source code a bit.  And no, I do not use `visual-line-mode`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the steps in the right direction -- I'll work on this over the next day or so as time permits -- greatly appreciated.

Comment: The maintainer of Aquamacs has included a function that accomplishes this goal:  `(defun visual-line-line-range () (save-excursion (cons (progn (vertical-motion 0) (point)) (progn (vertical-motion 1) (point)))))`:  https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/master/lisp/simple.el  He has also added this line of code to the minor-mode definition for visual-line-mode:  `(set (make-local-variable 'hl-line-range-function) #'visual-line-line-range)`.  Alternatively, this line of code may be used:  `(setq hl-line-range-function 'visual-line-line-range) `

Comment: This kinda works, but when the previous line has less free columns available than the maximum, the highlight extends back over the previous line.